# Intel Integrated Graphics Performance

Tags: release-loki, graphics, intel, performance

i am using Asus E403SA laptop and graphics performance in Elementary OS Loki 0.4.1 is not as good as in Windows 10 Pro. As I am a new Loki user, can you guide me through the process of updating/fixing this driver. I use  Integrated Intel HD Graphics 400 (Braswell).
Thanks.

Comment: Every Linux distro has a problem the graphics will never compare to Windows or Mac because X11 is not well done developed, if you want to use intel graphics driver just `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`

Answer (score 1):

To install updated drivers for all hardware run the following command in a terminal and reboot your system once it completes, [reference](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack):

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`

To get the latest stable graphics drivers (for better performance and compatibility with newer games) you can add [this PPA](http://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu) to your system.

Answer (score -1):

I use Intel HD 5500 and elementary is soooo smoth even with high cpu usage.

since you use new CPU you might try new kernel 4.11.

Comment: i saw here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_E403SA, that i should install xf86-video-intel, but i dont know how. Can you help?

Comment: did you had to install any additional graphics drivers?